# Browser game with PHP, Java, HTML and CSS

Tags: java, php, html, css, web-development-server

Hello programmers around the world, I am currently working on my own browser game and I ran into a problem when trying to register an account and store the details into a database. I am currently using PHP in order to do it. When I enter the registration details username, email, password ...etc. and hit the register button nothing happens. The result should be that the values should be stored in a database and you should be redirected to another page.

Note I am using my own server which I made in Java the code is below:

```
package server.java;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {

    ServerSocket serversocket;

    //entry point for our program
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().runServer(); // to avoid any problems with static fields
    }

    public void runServer() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Server is started!");
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(4567); //port number at which the server is running 

        //for accepting requests
        acceptRequest();
    }

    private void acceptRequest() throws Exception{
        while(true){ // we have to accept all the requests
            //connection to the client is in the form of socket which contains the stream for input and output
            Socket s = serversocket.accept();
            ConnectionHandler ch = new ConnectionHandler(s);

            //ch is the thread, so we have to strt the thread
            ch.start();// this line of code will call the run() method automatically 
        }
    }
}

package server.java;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

//this class basically handles all the connections which contain the requests
public class ConnectionHandler extends Thread{ //by extending to Thread, this class becoomes a Thread

    Socket s;

    //for sending the output to the client
    PrintWriter pw;

    //for getting the input from the client
    BufferedReader br;

    //constructor which accepts and uses a Socket
    public ConnectionHandler(Socket s) throws Exception{
        this.s = s;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    }

    /*
     *Thread class contains a method run() which is called automatically when we start the thread
     *in this method we have to read the request and give the responce
     */
     public void run(){ 
          try{
               //here we get the request string and give this string to the HttpRequest class
               String requestString = "";

               //from br we have to read our request
               //read until request is not of length 0 or br is ready
              while(br.ready() || requestString.length() == 0){
                    requestString += (char) br.read();
              }
              System.out.println(requestString);// for testing purposes

              HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(requestString);

              //now we pass the HttpRequest object to HttpResponce in order to get the responce
              HttpResponce responce = new HttpResponce(request);

              //write the final output to pw
              pw.write(responce.responce.toCharArray());
              pw.close();
              br.close();
              s.close();
          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

     }

}

package server.java;

public class HttpRequest {

    //first line contains 3 parts, 1 - request type, 2 - file name, 3 - http version
    //for us only the file name is important
    String filename;

    //we have to create a constructor which accepts a string as input
    public HttpRequest(String request){

         //now we have the request from which only the fisrt line matters to us
         String lines[] = request.split("\n");// now we have all the lines of the request separated

         //this line basically splits the first line, and then selcets the second item which is our filename
        filename = lines[0].split(" ")[1];
    }
}

package server.java;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class HttpResponce {

     HttpRequest request;

     //this is the final responce which is generated
     String responce;

     //root path of the server
     String root = "E:/root";

     //we have to create a constructor which accepts a request as input
     public HttpResponce(HttpRequest request) throws Exception{
           this.request = request;

           //now we have to open the file mentioned in request
           File f = new File(root + this.request.filename);

           try{
               responce = "HTTP/1.1 200  \r\n"; //version of http and 200 for status code
               //200 means everything is okay

               responce += "Server: Our Java Server/1.0 \r\n"; //identity of the server
               responce += "Content-Type: text/html \r\n"; //responce is in html format
               responce += "Connection: close \r\n";//this line tells the browser to close the connection because no transmitions
               responce += "Content-Length: " + f.length() + " \r\n"; //lngth of the responce file
               responce += "\r\n"; //after blank line we have to append file data

               //to read this file
               FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

               int s;
               while((s = fis.read()) != -1){ //-1 means end of file
                     responce += (char) s;
               }
               fis.close();
          }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
               //if we dont get a file then error 404
               responce = responce.replace("200", "404");
          }
          catch(Exception e){
               //if other error then 500 internal server error
               responce = responce.replace("200", "500");
          }
      }
 }
```

This is the entire code for my Java server.
Note: I think the server is working fine because it load and transitions between HTML pages. When it comes to PHP pages though it doesn't do anything so maybe it is the problem. I've been trying to solve this problem for two weeks now with no success so far? If somebody would be so kind as to help it would be really appreciated. Sending the code for the PHP page now:

```
<?php
     session_start();

     //connect to the database
     $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Smd497_497", "users");

     if(isset($_POST['register'])){
          $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
          $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
          $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
          $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password2']);

          if($password == $password2){
              //create user
              $password = md5($password); //hash password before storing it for security purposes
              $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
              mysqli_query($db, $sql);
              $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration successful!";
              header('Location: choice.php'); //redirect to the next page
           else{
                //failed to create user
                $_SESSION['message'] = "The passwords DO NOT match!";
           }
     }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Registration page</title>
     <style type="text/css">
           body{
                background-position: top;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
           }
           .starwars{
                 margin-left: 525px;
           }
           .blyat{
                 position: relative;
                 text-align; center;
                 margin-left: 325px;
           }

           .registration{
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 80px;
                  left: 22%;
                  font-size: 30px;
                  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                  padding-bottom: 5px;
           }

           .details{
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 130px;
                  left: 14%;
           }

           form {
                margin-left: 100px;
           }

      </style>
 </head>
 <body background = "https://pre00.deviantart.net/c83b/th/pre/i/2013/067/0/1/star_wars_sith_or_jedi_by_misterrecord-d5xdgdq.png">
         <div class = "starwars">
              <img src = "https://novaopenstore.com/Image/EventContainerImage/30" height = "100" width = "300" />
         </div>
         <div class = "blyat">
             <img src = "https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/30629292_1627559157293346_4622477325102925006_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=82718a4b31b952272b36d8a374a0ae14&oe=5B712921" height = "425" width = "700"/>
             <div class = "registration"><b>Registration Details</b></div>
             <div class = "details">
             <form class="form" action="register.php" method="post">
                   <div class="alert-error"><?= $_SESSION['message'] ?></div>
                   Choose you battlefield!<br>
                   Battlefield: <select>
                       <option value="Battlefield 1">Battlefield 1</option>
                   </select><br>
                   Choose your name!<br>
                   Username: <input type="text" name="username" required /><br>
                   Choose your email!<br>
                   Email: <input type="text" name = "email" required /><br>
                   Choose your password!<br>
                   Password: <input type="password" name="password" required/><br>
                   Confirm your password!<br>
                   Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="password2" required/><br>
                   <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"/>
              </form>
              </div>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Note: I am currently not having any problems with HTML or CSS (at least not any I know of...) Another useful thing to say is that some of you might think that my server is not working or that it is not receiving the information. Last time I tried I got the following result:
**username=zexstoi&email=ss%40mail.bg&password=147852369&password2=147852369&register=Register
**
This is evidence that the server is receiveing the right info just not processing it right for some reason could be the server or the PHP page.As said above if anybody has any idea for a fix please share it with me and the rest of the community. Have a nice day everybody!

Comment: Are you getting anything if you do `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: @IcedAnt No, not sure what I am supposed to get though...

Comment: You are supposed to be getting the name/value pairs from the form. Remove `action="register.php"` and try again. I assume you are using the `var_dump` at the top of your PHP.

Comment: @IcedAnt I don't think I am using the command in the write place also I am using notepad ++ so in that case do I need to use a print_r statement somewhere?

Comment: `print_r` is similar to `var_dump`. I run your code on Apache, only replacing the PHP part with `var_dump($_POST);` and it works fine, the problem is with your server.

Comment: @IcedAnt Thanks, at least I know that much now. Still though any ideas on a possible fix? I don't know what could be wrong with the server. :( The full code is posted above the PHP code. It contains four different classes. Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: I can't really help you with Java, just a few more tips on PHP. `mysql_*` functions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed in PHP 7.0.0, replace them with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Don't use `*_real_escape_string` or `md5` for passwords, use `password_hash` and `password_verify`. Have fun!

Comment: @IcedAnt Thanks a lot for you help! At least now I know where the mistake is. Looking forward to talking to you again.